# How to iterate through values in array to match value in objects and return corresponding object?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, lodash

I try to search any of the value I got in an array inside an other array with lot of objects. 
I try to use lodash but vanilla is ok too.

My reference array is like so:

```
let array1 = ["value1", "value2", "value8", "value9"]
```

I want to find those value in this array of objects:

```
let array2 = [{
  key1: xxx
  key2: value1
  key3: xxxx
}, {
  key1: value2
  key2: xxxx
  key3: xxxx
}, {
  key1: xxx
  key2: xxx
  key3: value3
}]
```

I've tried

```
let finalData: []

let filterData = _.filter(array2, array1);
this.finalData = filterData
```

I expect to return an array with all match object:

```
[{
  key1: xxx
  key2: value1
  key3: xxxx
}, {
  key1: xxx
  key2: value2
  key3: xxxx
}]
```

I just get an empty array all the time.
Do i need to combien a for each method to do that ?

BONUS: if it could return an error with an array of the not found values (value8, value9) this would be cherry on the cake.

Comment: `array2.filter(it => array1.includes(it.key2))`

Comment: Is possible that the values you are trying to find are not always on the `key2`, i.e, we should look on all the keys of the objects, or just on a particular one?

Comment: @Shidersz, sorry this was not precised, indeed the value could be placed anywhere. I've updated my example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
let array1 = ["value1", "value2", "value8", "value9"];
let array2 = [
  {
    "key1": "xxx",
    "key2": "value1",
    "key3": "xxxx"
  }, {
    "key1": "xxx",
    "key2": "value2",
    "key3": "xxxx"
  },
  {
    "key1": "xxx",
    "key2": "value3",
    "key3": "xxxx"
  }
];

// copy the original array1
let noMatch = [...array1];

// iterate (and filter) through every element
// that array2 contains
let match = array2.filter(elem => {
  // iterate through every key in the element
  for (const key in elem) {
    // check if array1 has the value
    const found = array1.find(e => e === elem[key]);
    if (found) {
      // remove from noMatch the matched value
      noMatch = noMatch.filter(e => e !== found);
      // found
      return true;
    }
  }
  // Not found
  return false;
});

// matched elements
console.log('match', match);
// values that didn't match any element
console.log('noMatch', noMatch);
```

Comment: This work very well thanks !! Any idea how I could get an array of value which wasn't found  ["value8", "value9"] ?
I tried to add a else if but i don't know how to get the array1 value in that case...

Comment: @NuoNuoLeRobot check the edit.

Comment: this is just perfect, with comments and everything ! thanks a lot for your time this is life saving !